# How to get the file's URL before uploading it to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload files in the background without depending on Firebase RTDB updates. I would like to generate a file's URL independent of the Google Cloud Storage upload progress.

Is this possible? If so, what would be the better approach for Mobile clients (Android and iOS)?

Comment: Yes you can generate a file url. Unclear of which files.

Comment: What exact kind of URL you want to get? One that will allow anyone to read the file (i.e. your data is public) OR one that allow accessing a file that is not public?

Comment: It's better to wait until the file is fully uploaded, so the URL actually works before anyone sees it.